# how is に used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I just need clarification of how it was used in this particular sentence

> 相対的になされるべきで 一部ではなく全体のバランスが対象に

I'm just confused why there is a に at the end I did check the video if the voice actor said anything else but this the ending of the sentence and how に is used in succession I seem to have a hard time trying to understand how it is used

> 分かるでしょ？→ 王子様はもっとこう　上目遣いで 恥じらいながら誘うように！→ 僕は　誘ってるの知りながら 意地悪するみたいに！→ もう１回　よろしく！ はあ…

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was explained where I came to learn it: に particle specifies the target to a verb. And to me this general definition seems to make sense in most cases. So when the particle is used without a verb it can be a way for the speaker to make the target clear or basically lead the audience to what they have in mind without having to complete the sentence. I don’t know if it’s strictly grammatically speaking correct though.

In the first example it seems to me that the speaker is asking for what comes before the に particle. In the rest depending on the context it can be different but it seems to me that the speaker wants to explain what they have in their mind and are trying to lead the audience to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first に:
相対的 - relative
相対的に - relatively

The second:
対象に - [dative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case) of 対象(object). Probably the word なる (become) was omitted

The third:
ように - ように should be taken as a whole word, which means "in order to" or "as advice".

1. 早く寝るように (you should sleep early)、母が言った (mom said) - as advice
2. 早く起きるように (in order to wake up early)、早く寝た (I slept early) - in order to

The fourth:
みたいに - preposition/conjunction "like", introducing an adverbial clause. For example, 意地悪するみたいに (like I'm teasing)

As you can see, に has lots of usages, but basic usages are just two:

1. After indirect objects, or "dative" case
2. After something adverbial